# How many coefficients do you need to determine a modular form

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms

Here is the question i'm particularly interested in :

Let $f$ be a modular form, suppose we know the $a_p(f)$ for all but finitely many prime $p$. Is this enough to know the modular forms i.e. to know all the $a_n$ ? If it is true can you give a proof or reference ?

I'm also interested (but it's less important) in the following related question ?

Is there an algorithmic way to compute the $a_n$ ?

Is there a least amount of coefficients that you need to know to compute all the others ?

Comment: If you know the weight and level of $f$, then you only need finitely many coefficients. This follows from the fact that the space of modular forms of a given weight and level is finite-dimensional.

Comment: Ah yes indeed ! and in my case I do know this information so that does answer my question. Now just for my curiosity : what if you don't know the level and weight ? How about the other questions ? Thansk a lot :)

Comment: Although ... is it clear that knowing the $a_p(f)$ for all but finitely $p$ works ? I mean ... we don't know in which coefficients the informations is contained right ? Maybe i'm missing something ? Or maybe you were not claiming to answer my question ?

Comment: It's not yet clear because a priori those coefficients could e.g. all turn out to be the same.

Comment: But if you intend $f$ to be a Hecke eigenform, so that $a_p(f)$ are Hecke eigenvalues, then probably there is more you can say.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot ;) let's hope someone answers !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As posed, the answer is clearly "no": it's not enough to know all but finitely many prime coefficients. To see why, let $f$ be your favourite non-zero modular form (of some weight $k$ and level $N$); then $g(z) = f(2z)$ is a modular form of weight $k$ and level $2N$, and $a_p(g) = 0$ for every prime $p$ except 2. But $g$ is not zero.

If you know that $f$ is a *newform*, then knowing $a_p(f)$ for all but finitely many $p$ is enough to determine $f$; this is a deep and significant theorem (the "strong multiplicity one" theorem) and I don't think there's an easy way to make it algorithmic. (At least, if you don't know the weight and the level beforehand then you're definitely in trouble. If you know the weight and level, then there are algorithms which will allow you to compute all the newforms of that weight and level, and then you can just check to see which one has the $a_p$'s you expect.)

Comment: That's too bad :) Thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: @David, if $f$ is a newform of some square-free level $N$ and weight k does there exist  coefficients $a_{p^{2}}(f)$, for $p\not|  N$ ?